# WordPress load posts with year and category filter

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to implement category and year(from post publish date) filter. To do this I have used the following URL structure:

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2016/?cat=5

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2015/?cat=5

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2014/?cat=5

Here the years are from post date and 5 is the category id.

So all the above links works but when I click on 2017 to go to
http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2017/?cat=5

It does not show any post. But there are two posts in 2017 with category id 5.

[image]

If I open the blog page http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/test/ the post from 2017 shows up.

May I know what might be the reason for the posts to not appear in

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2017/?cat=5

**Code:**

category-tidligere-udstillinger.php

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <?php $image_size = ( get_field('image_disable_force_ratio') ) ? 'blog-thumb-normal' : 'blog-thumb'; ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( $image_size ); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/no-thumbnail.jpg" alt="No thumbnail">'; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php 
            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        endif; ?>

        <?php get_sidebar('exhibition'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also if I check just the yearly archives:

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2012/

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2016/

works but

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2017

does not show any post.

Comment: how can we help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: Hi Niraj. I thought may be I don't need to add any code for this. Since I guess the issue might be coming from how the posts are set or may be the permalink.

Comment: The issue is from the theme you are using, when your URL queries for year & category, the theme category template is not querying it to db. So you need to check your category page code

Comment: Ok. I have built the theme on my own. But since you are asking I will add the code just to make sure that the problem is understood.

Comment: Also can you double check that the test post is having date published as 2017 and belongs to category id `5`?

Comment: Yes. I have cross checked that several times and also tried adding a new post for test. But it does not show up. You can check the image I added to question. And also the code which is a simple loop.

Comment: Also if I check just the yearly archives:

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2012/

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2016/

works but

http://www.horsenskunstmuseum.dk/2017

does not show any post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring because there was a media file with the name '2017.jpg'. I renamed the media file and the archives loaded properly. Strange issue though.

I didn't know media file names can create a conflict with archive name.

If any one has any idea on this feel free to comment.

Comment: Probably due to the mod_rewrite  -f flag in the .htaccess, wp wont process the url if a file with that string exists, or spaghetti code in the core's rewrite rules :p